# How to get APPEND_SLASH to work properly with nginx rewrite?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have this in nginx config

```
location /todjango/ {
    rewrite ^/todjango(/.*)$ $1 break;
    uwsgi_pass django;
}
```

In `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("foo/", include("foo.urls"))
]
```

APPEND_SLASH is `True` by default

When I type `curl http://localhost:8000/todjango/foo` I want to get 301 to `/todjango/foo/`, but instead I get 301 to `/foo/`. When APPEND_SLASH is `False` I get 404 as expected